# UTF_8 in smarty

Tags: php, html, utf-8, smarty

I have a simple page in smarty  and I want to display this "سلام" but smarty  shows "????"

This my php file:

```
require '../libs/Smarty.class.php';
$smarty = new Smarty;

//$smarty->force_compile = true;
$smarty->debugging = true;
$smarty->caching = true;
$smarty->cache_lifetime = 120;

$smarty->assign("word", "سلام", true);

$smarty->display('index.tpl');
```

Then I have add this to my header.tpl :

```
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
```

Comment: just save everything (.tpl, .php, .css, .html) in utf-8 without bom

Comment: You need to save your PHP file with  correct UTF-8 encoding. Make sure your editor allow you to choose encoding, otherwise - change your editor.

Comment: i want to config smarty in index.php and header.tpl not in all files and i use netbeans ide that suport full utf-8 encoding work without smarty good and display my word Correctly. wich class or code in index.php in smarty can solve my problem.

Comment: This has nothing to do with Smarty. Keep the `Content-Type` meta tag in the header and, most important, save all the files as UTF-8 without BOM. That's all.